# Why I am getting form re-submission alert in angular reactive form?

Tags: angular

**Problem:**

when I navigate to a page with a form and when I reload it it shows resubmit alert but when I open the URL in another tab the issue is not there. Can someone suggest me any idea about this?. I tried lot to find out a solution to this but I was unable to do so.

Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe your using `(submit)` instead of `ngSubmit()`, but it would be easier to help if you added some example code demonstrating the problem. Adding a StackBlitz too would help.